# Modelling dark energy as a potential?

Tags: gravity, general-relativity, dark-energy

Dark energy is the cosmological constant.However can we model dark energy as some form of field with a corresponding potential?

Comment: See for example [quintessence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintessence_(physics)).